# tensorflow_text disables GPU on colab

Tags: tensorflow, text, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Yesterday everything was working with the transformer. Now I can not use the GPU provided on colab. This works:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

!pip install -q tensorflow_datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow_text
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
#import tensorflow_text as text
print(tf.__version__)
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Output:

```
2.4.1
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

If I uncomment tensorflow_text import then:

```
!pip install -q tensorflow_datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow_text
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_text as text
print(tf.__version__)
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-adc8722d8d1e> in <module>()
      5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
----> 7 import tensorflow_text as text
      8 print(tf.__version__)
      9 device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
     55   Raises:
     56     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
---> 57   """
     58   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
     59   try:

NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/_text_similarity_metric_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow15OpKernelContext15allocate_outputEN4absl14lts_2020_09_2311string_viewERKNS_11TensorShapeEPPNS_6TensorE
```

If I terminate the GPU session and connect again to hosted runtime I get with the imported tensorflow_text:

```
2.5.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-adc8722d8d1e> in <module>()
      9 device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
     10 if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
---> 11   raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
     12 print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))

SystemError: GPU device not found
```

For some reason now the version has changed to 2.5.0 tensorflow_text can be imported but the GPU is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I now enforce the old tensorflow_text version:

```
!pip install -q tensorflow_text==2.4.1
```

This seems to work !

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

!pip install -q tensorflow_datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow_text==2.4.1

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_text as text
print(tf.__version__)
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found {}'.format(device_name))
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Output:

```
2.4.1
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

Thanks for support !